# Is there a way to find an xpath in selenium, see if it contains the text I want, and then find preceding text?

Tags: python, xpath

I am fairly new to webscraping with selenium and have been stumped on this problem for awhile. My objective is to find the amount of injuries on a team. The issue that I have been running into is that I want to be able to find the injuries based on what team I pick, and the team is different every time. For example, if I wanted to check how many players are injured on Colorado, I would like to search for Colorado and then be able to extract the injuries. I have come up with the following code.

```
from selenium import webdriver
    
driver = webdriver.Chrome('C:\\Users\\Carl\\Downloads\\chromedriver.exe')  
    
teams = ['Colorado', 'Kentucky', 'Iowa', 'Nebraska', 'Rutgers', 'Syracuse',
                         'Oregon', 'San Diego', 'Michigan State']
    
driver.get("https://www.covers.com/sport/football/ncaaf/injuries")
    
#I would like to do it similiar to this way, where I can plug in the team name
first = driver.find_element_by_id('Colorado')

#This is where ALL team injuries are located for every team
injuries = first.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@class='col-xs-2 col-sm-3']").text

#This extracts the injuries for Air Force not Colorado
print(injuries)
    
driver.quit()
```

In the code above it retrieves Air Forces injured players and not Colorado's. The website I am scraping is https://www.covers.com/sport/football/ncaaf/injuries. I greatly appreciate the help, thanks!

[HTML structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t8cF4.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want your XPath to be relative from the selected element. You are "jumping up to the top" and looking down the entire document, finding the first matching element.

```
injuries = first.find_element_by_xpath(".//div[@class='col-xs-2 col-sm-3']").text
```

Though, it would be better to be a little more precise, selecting the first section that is a following-sibling, and then select the div that is a descendant from that section:

```
injuries = first.find_element_by_xpath("following-sibling::section[1]//div[@class='col-xs-2 col-sm-3']").text
```